# MudBlazor: how to set window size?

Tags: blazor

When I start my Blazor server app it shows large browser window.
It is not Full-screen but it occupied the screen.
How can I change the window size ?

Comment: Can you please describe what you've tried so far? I can't  figure out what you're trying to do based off your question.

Comment: Do you want to make it fixed size ? Can user resize the window ?

Comment: I do not touch  the size and other window parameters, but when I start my Blazor App it opens window on entire screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is something that is possible with JavaScript when the page loads, but you cannot change the browser size from a Blazor (client or server) app.

Comment: I have setting in VS: run Chrome and Chrome is open and has a large window, VS run the new windows of the same size as already opened.